# Subtract from previous rows based on conditions

Tags: r

I have a following DF where i would like to poulate values under **TEST** for **RANK == 2** with the following logic.

**?** = MIN( (GROUP_VALUE - TEST[VALUE OF RANK = 1] ), GROUP_VALUE / POINT )

```
   country    GROUP_VALUE   RANK  POINT      TEST
1      USA       2000        1      2.5      1500
2      USA       2000        2      2.5      **?**
3       UK       1000        1      2.5      1000 
4      JPN       3000        1      3.5      1000
5      JPN       3000        2      3.5      **?**
```

Expected Output:

```
   country    GROUP_VALUE   RANK  POINT      TEST
1      USA       2000        1      2.5      1500
2      USA       2000        2      2.5     *500*
3       UK       1000        1      2.5      1000 
4      JPN       3000        1      3.5      1000
5      JPN       3000        2      3.5     *857.15*
```

I have tried with the following code but failed to get the expected output.

```
df$test = ifelse(df$rank == 2, min((df$GROUP_VALUE / df$point), df$group_value - lag(df$test), 0)
```

Comment: In your input dataframe what values do you have? Certainly not `**?**`. You should post the data exactly like it is, with no fancy formating, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr`. `mutate` is used to create the new column based on your conditions.  I also add a `group_by` stage so that we can delineate between countries.

```
library(dplyr)
df$TEST <- as.numeric(df$TEST)
df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(TEST = case_when(RANK == 2 ~ min(GROUP_VALUE - TEST[RANK == 1],GROUP_VALUE/POINT), TRUE ~ TEST))

#  country GROUP_VALUE  RANK POINT  TEST
#  <chr>         <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 USA            2000     1   2.5 1500 
#2 USA            2000     2   2.5  500 
#3 UK             1000     1   2.5 1000 
#4 JPN            3000     1   3.5 1000 
#5 JPN            3000     2   3.5  857.
```

Comment: With `ifelse` , `df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(TEST = ifelse(RANK == 2, min(GROUP_VALUE - TEST[RANK == 1],GROUP_VALUE/POINT), TEST))
`